# How can I place different elements in a List in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart

[image]

As in the image; How can I create a list structure where the list items can be selected, the user can enter data with the textField and I can use the Text() Widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) widget.

It accepts a list of widgets as it's children, so you are not limited to ListTile.

Code should look something like this:

```
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: <Widget>[
    
    Container(), //Your widget here
    Container(), //Your widget here,
    Container(), //Your widget here
    ...
  ],
)
```